# Android get value of the selected radio button

Tags: android, android-event

I have a RadioGroup `rg1` and I want to get the value of the selected radio button.

I know that I can get the `id` of the selected radio button by using:

```
if(rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId()!=-1)
int id= rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId()
```

that gives me the id , but I want the value of that button.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You need to get the radio button at that index, then get the value of the text of that button. Try this code below.

```
if(rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId()!=-1){
    int id= rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    View radioButton = rg1.findViewById(id);
    int radioId = radioGroup.indexOfChild(radioButton);
    RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) rg1.getChildAt(radioId);
    String selection = (String) btn.getText();
}
```

Comment: Is the id returned from getCheckedRadioButton only the id within the RadioGroup? Why couldn't you get the id of the button and then use a more general findViewById to get the RadioButton instad of adding extra steps of indexOfChild and getChildAt

Comment: What is radioGroup at int radioId = radioGroup.indexOfChild(radioButton);

Comment: radioGroup is the object of RadioGroup; That group contains all the radio button. It is parent for those radio button

Comment: so rg1 and radioGroup is the same object in that case, right?

Comment: Or you can get the radio button with their ID's and get its text if its checked using `isChecked` method. Like this `RadioButton radio_male = ((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbtn_male)); String gend = radio_male.isChecked() ? radio_male.getText().toString() : radio_female.getText().toString();`

Comment: Couldn't you simply have done - `(RadioButton) rg1.findViewById(id).getText();` ?

Answer (score 53):

try this:

```
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.youradio);
String radiovalue = ((RadioButton)findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();
```

Comment: thank you , i have got an answer already, hope i could select more than one answer as accepted answers :( , really thank you man, you always help me

Comment: Thanks you. 
You should validade if it is null beucase may crash the app.

Answer (score 3):

```
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.youradio);
String radiovalue = (RadioButton)this.findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

One Line Code

```
String buisnesstype = ((RadioButton) rdtranscompany.findViewById(rdtranscompany.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rb1=(RadioButton)findViewById(rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
```

Now you can use `rb1.getText()` to get the text on the Radiobutton that is checked

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this

```
RadioGroup rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.youradio);
String radiovalue=(RadioButton)this.findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RadioGroup bhktype_RadioGr = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.bhkypeRadioGroup);
int flatTypeId = bhktype_RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
String flat_type = ((RadioButton) findViewById(flatTypeId)).getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

SImple answer one line

```
View v = yourView;  // as a button

String radiovalue = (RadioButton)v).getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the radio button text only when a radio button is checked in a radio group by this **Kotlin** code -

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { rg, i ->
    val selectedId = radioGroup.checkedRadioButtonId
    val radioButton = findViewById<RadioButton>(selectedId)
    myTextView.text = radioButton.text
}
```