# How to get radio Button values number

Tags: android, listview

I am making an application that has list and Radio Buttons. My Layout contains of the following : a list , A button .

The List contains of Radio buttons. Two radio Buttons. After checking the buttons. I want to make a loop that reads the values of how many are in Button one and how many in Button Two. 
This is how I have done so far.

```
        ListViewStudentEditAbsence country ;

            for(int i=0;i<listViewStudentNames.size();i++) {
                country = listViewStudentNames.get(i);
                if (country.getAbsence()==1) {
                    Absence[i] = "1";
                } else {
                    Absence[i] ="0";
                }
            }
```

But It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: did u debug the code does it enter the block of if or else ? because you have used == i would recommend to use .equalsignoreCase

Comment: It doesn't go inside the for loop

Comment: have a look here on how its done -- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html  -- radio and checkboxes use the (isChecked();) when something is selected

Comment: not proper information. post you complete Scenario.

Comment: @HradeshKumar, What information that you need to know ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `CustomAdapter` `getView()` method

```
int value=0; //globally
    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);        
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
                  if (checkedId == R.id.rbutton1) {
                    value=10;  //a's value
                } else if (checkedId == R.id.rbutton2) {
                    value=20; //b's value
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have tried that, My app crashed. Indeed, I want to make a loop that starts with a click of a button in my activity. The loop reads each radio Button and their values are stored in an array.

Answer (score 0):

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194515/android-get-value-of-the-selected-radio-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179124/android-getting-value-from-selected-radiobutton)

[Android getting value from selected radiobutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179124/android-getting-value-from-selected-radiobutton)

Hope it works. This two links give you proper knowledge about fetching value.

Comment: Recommendation of links should be in comments