# How to get text from a radio button in android

Tags: android, radio-button

So I'm writing an app that requires me to have a radio group, and when a certain radio button is clicked in that group, points get added to the total.

So far, I have

```
int radiobuttonid = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
rb = (RadioButton) findViewbyId(radiobuttonId);
```

This is to get what radio button is pressed, but I have no idea how to get a string/text from the button to form my if-else statements. Any ideas?

Comment: The answer is already in another post... Link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194515/android-get-value-of-the-selected-radio-button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android get value of the selected radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194515/android-get-value-of-the-selected-radio-button)

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code. If there is no text. it will return an empty string `""`

`((RadioButton) findViewbyId(radiobuttonId)).getText().toString()`